# URLSession.shared.dataTask(...) doesn't work

Tags: swift3, xcode8, nsurlsession, shared

I could not find any solution, can you please help me...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = user.name

    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "lukas")

    if let profileImageURL = user.profileImageURL {
        var url = NSURL(string: profileImageURL)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

[image: img]

Comment: Btw, it's missing `.resume()` to start the task.

Answer (score 0):

The (Swift 3) compiler wants native `URL` (without `NS`)

```
let url = URL(string: profileImageURL)
```